# Nested loops C++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, nested-loops, do-while

So I am making a program that will create a square based on the users desired size. My code so far reads the value, prints out the top of the square but i'm getting caught up on how to set up the sides because of a nested loop I've created. The issue here is that I need for the loop to reset it's values every time it exists.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int,char**) {
  int x;
  int z=1;
  int l=0;
  int n=0;
  int q=1;
  int m=0;
  int o=0;
  do{
    cout << "Enter length between 0 and 64 (-1 to exit): ";
    cin >> x;
    if (x>-1&&x<64){
      cout << "+";
      for (;x-2!=n;++n){
        cout << "-";
      }
      cout << "+" << endl;
    }
    else{
      cout << "Length must be between 0 and 64 inclusive, or enter -1 to exit.";
    }
    do {
      cout << "|";
      do {
        //cout << " ";
        //++m;
        //}while (x-2!=m);
        cout << "|" << endl;
        ++o;
      }
      while (x-2!=o);
      ++z;
    }
    while (z!=5);
  }
```

The commented out portion is where the program is getting caught up at, it seems that when I increment m until it exits the do while loop, it holds onto the value that it was incremented to. I know that a continue statement breaks from the loop and begins a new iteration of the loop but it doesn't seem to want to fit inside the do-while loop even if i create an if statement such as

```
if (x-2==m){
continue;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `while (z=1);` is definitely wrong.

Comment: This part: `(x>-1||x<64)`  is broken because the " || " means OR so I can just pick a number bigger than -1  (2000) or lower than 64 (-2000).
You have to put the '&&' to make it an AND.
You can read here some more about operators in C and C++: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @PaulRooney I need the program to run 5 times so i fixed the loop function. Thanks for the catch or else it would run in a loop forever.

Comment: @RandomProgrammer Thanks for the heads up, I mistakenly put or instead of and

Comment: With those lines commented out, your braces aren't balanced. Post the code that you're having problems with, not a modified version.

Comment: Instead of `do-while`, use a `for` loop that counts up the number of spaces you want to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `m = 0;` before the loop.

```
m = 0;
do {
    cout << ' ';
    ++m;
} while (x-2 != m);
```

Or use a `for` loop instead;

```
for (int m = 0; m != x-2; m++) {
    cout << ' ';
}
```

This is the more common idiom for repeating something a certain number of times, since you can see all the conditions related to the loop in a single place.

Comment: why does the placement of the int definition matter? In this case, int m was never touched until the nested do while loop. It works now but i don't understand why the placement had effected the loop. I'll start using it as a norm to group together defining ints before their connected loop, it definitely helps to see them. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: The variable that's used to index the `for` loop isn't needed outside of the loop, so you declare it locally.